# Python Mongo: Using '$or' in queries to mongo

Tags: python, mongodb

I am confused as to why the following two queries are returning different results.

```
modelObj = connection.MyModel.find({'t': t,
               '$or': [{'cpd': None}, {'cpd': {'$gte': yesterday}}]})
```

and

```
modelObj = connection.MyModel.find({'t': t,
               'cpd': {'$in': [None, {'$gte': yesterday}]}})
```

The explain plan for both of them is more or less same.

The second query seems to be ignoring the "'$gte': yesterday" condition.

Can anyone explain me why is this happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$in` can only be used to match a field against an array of discrete values, not other operators.